# How do I implement a good game menu in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, menu

I have been working on a Java game for a while that I started back in my college days. After taking considerable breaks due to my professional career, I'm getting back to it and realizing how awful the code is. I basically had a "monolithic main" with both GUI and game logic in the same class file. What I'm attempting to do, is abstract and "componentize" the GUI into smaller chunks. My executed class extends *JFrame* which I add and remove panels to/from when buttons are clicked. Ex.

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    private JPanel[] _panels = {new MainPanel(), new OptionsPanel(), new DifficultyPanel()};
    private int _currentPanelIndex = 0;
    public GameFrame(){
        ...
        add(_panels[_currentPanelIndex]);
        ...
    }
}
```

Within each panel class, I have private *ActionListeners* for the buttons. In *MainPanel*, I'm getting the singleton *GameFrame* instance and setting the current panel kind of like:

```
class SinglePlayerButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        GameFrame instance = GameFrame.getInstance();
        JPanel[] panels = instance.getPanels();
        int currentPanelIndex = instance.getCurrentPanelIndex();
        instance.remove(panels[currentPanelIndex]);
        int newPanelIndex;
        for(newPanelIndex = 0; newPanelIndex < panels.length; newPanelIndex++){
            if(panels[newPanelIndex] instanceof DifficultyPanel){
                break;
            }
        }
        instance.add(panels[newPanelIndex]);
    }
}
```

I do not like this deep of coupling in my classes, but I can live with it. However, the real problem is that when I click the last button that takes me into the game, I can't have:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    GameFrame.getInstance().startGame();
}
```

because this will cause my game to run in the Java *Event* thread, thereby disallowing any other events from being handled. Previously, I had a busy while loop:

```
...
while(waiting){
    //Do nothing
}
remove(_panels[_currentPanelIndex]);
startGame();
...
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    waiting = false;
}
```

What is the best way to let my *GameFrame* class know that I've clicked the play button? Can I send an event or message to it from one of its sub-panels telling it to start, and if so, how do I keep the game from running in the *Event* thread? Should I handle it in the *actionPerformed()* method and simply spawn a new thread? I would prefer to keep it in the main thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go for [Slick 2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) (a lightweight OpenGL 2D game development framework with lots of cool stuff) or [Nifty-GUI](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/).

Slick has also some examples and tutorials and is easy to learn, for example the `StateBasedGame` can easily be used to implement multiple in-game menus (such as main menu, settings menu, in-game options, in-game pause/resume etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the game logic executing on it's own thread of execution, possibly when the user clicks a button.  I don't understand your prior approach with the while(wait) - that would still create problems if your game logic did some time consuming calculation that prevented the even thread from doing updates because the even thread does not stop executing when you call startGame().

EDIT:

It's not clear from the code you pasted that the GUI updates and the game logic are happening on seperate threads of execution - you might want to demonstrate that in your code.

Comment: Right, and I have the logic in a separate thread, but the drawing must be done in the thread running the GUI, right? 

My approach with the while loop was to hold off painting the screen with the game world until the play button was clicked. You're right that the event thread doesn't stop executing, but when you run the game _in_ the event thread, nothing else can run in it, including any other events which get fired.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to prevent the containers that contain the world from being redrawn?

Comment: I'm afraid I misspoke. I typed the above code from memory and didn't realize that the game is entirely single-threaded at the moment. Due to this, the GameFrame class is driving the GUI and the game logic and active rendering. If I make them run on separate threads, I am still stuck with the problem of making the game play start. It's the progression from GUI to game simulation that I can't resolve. How do I tell the simulation to begin?

Comment: Can't you just create a new thread and run the simulation start routine in there?